# LOG.trace enabled in maven 3

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, maven-3

I have a class: MyClass

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

Somewhere in my code I do a `LOG.trace()` only `LOG.isTraceEnabled()`

And a test for that MyClass which uses Junit4

the test is ran by maven (2.2.1) just fine and logs the other logs (I've set the log4j.xml to level=`INFO`)

But if I switch to maven 3.0.3, the log4j.xml gets overridden or it not pointing where is should be and all the levels of debug are enabled (debug, trace, etc.)

I want to disable, if possible trace logging as it works in maven 2.2.1. There are hacky ways that I can do, I know, but I want to understand why is this happening?

Some of the key dependencies from the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
</plugin>
```

the test is ran with other test classes. (multi-module project)
if I do   `mvn clean test -Dtest=MyClassTest`, the logging don't get messed up, but if I do mvn clean test (for all the tests) the logging will not work okay anymore (this is still just in case for maven 3)